# Rhino mocks when called get argument

Tags: c#, mocking, rhino-mocks

I’ve a repository like the below:

```
internal class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public virtual ITable GetTable()
    {
        return _context.GetTable<T>();
    }

    public virtual void InsertOnSubmit(T entity)
    {
        GetTable().InsertOnSubmit(entity);
    }

    public virtual void SubmitChanges()
    {
        _context.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Now the System under Test class is like the one below:

```
public class CustomerHelper
{
    private readonly IRepository<Customer> _customerRepository;
    CustomerHelper(IRepository<Customer> customerRepository)
    {
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    public void CreateCustomer(int createdBy, int customerId)
    {
        var customerToUpdate = _customerRepository.Get.Single(c => c.Id == customerId)

        customerToUpdate.CreatedBy =createdBy;
        customerToUpdate.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;

        _customerRepository.InsertOnSubmit(customerToUpdate);
        _customerRepository.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

My test method to the CreateCustomer method like the below, using RhinoMocks.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateCustomer()
{
    // Arrange
    Customer customer = new Customer
    {
        Id = 1
    };
    IRepository<Customer> repository =  MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRepository<Customer>>();
    var customerList = new List<Customer> { customer }.AsQueryable();

    repository.Stub(n => n.Get).Return(nonLaborclassificationList);

    CustomerHelper helper = new Customer(repository);
    helper.CreateCustomer(1, customer.Id);

    // Now here I would liek to test whether CreatedBy, CreateDate fields on    cutomer are updated correctly. I've tried the below

    Customer customerToUpdate;

    repository.Stub(c => c.InsertOnSubmit(customer)).WhenCalled(c => { customerToUpdate = n.Arguments[0]; } );
    Assert.AreEqual(1, customerToUpdate.CreatedBy);
}
```

The above code is not working. The place where I am stubbing `InsertOnSubmit()` method , trying to get the `customerToUpdate` instance from `CreateCustomer()` method. How do I write asserts to make sure that `CreatedBy`, `CreateDate` set properly?

Comment: `nonLaborclassificationList` is returned when you're stubbing `Get` (is that a property or what? I don't see it on the Repository<T> class you show above), but it's never defined anywhere in this code.

Answer (score 0):

The general strategy is this:

1. Stub the repository to return the particular customer you want updated
2. Take the necessary action, i.e. `helper.CreateCustomer()`
3. See if the object you originally stubbed has the right values set

In this case, you probably can just check the first Customer object you created which is stubbed into the repository. The actual code you're testing is using the same object (same reference), so you really don't need the last bit of code where you get the object from `InsertOnSubmit()`. However, if you still want to do that you can use `AssertWasCalled` to help:

```
repository.AssertWasCalled(
  x => x.InsertOnSubmit(Arg<Customer>.Matches(c => c.CreateBy))
```

For debugging, there's also a `GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn` method that is useful if you can step through with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues in your code:

1. As Jeff Bridgman says in comment, `nonLaborclassificationList` is not defined. I assume `customerList` should be returned instead.
2. `InsertOnSubmit()` for `repository` is stubbed after test action `helper.CreateCustomer(1, customer.Id)` is executed. So this stub does not work.
   Stub should be set before test action, as *Arrange* goes before *Act*.

And, of course, if you want to assert whether `CreatedDate` is set correctly, you have to write particular `Assert` for that :) .